# SSL problems using Twilio

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to use Twilio to send SMS. I'm using their templates to send my first test message:

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client(my_SID, my_TOKEN)

message = client.messages \
                .create(
                     body="Join Earth's mightiest heroes. Like Kevin Bacon.",
                     from_= number1,
                     to= number2
                 )

print(message.sid)
```

I've manually replaced the SID and the TOKEN with their respective values as per Twilio's console (the `os.environ[]` function doesn't work). The thing is, this error appearas as I try to run the code:

```
PS C:\Users\USER> & C:/Users/USER/anaconda3/python.exe "d:/Escritorio/amigo secreto/send_sms.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 688, in urlopen
    conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 280, in _get_conn
    return conn or self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 979, in _new_conn
    raise SSLError(
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twilio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACfd9e165c0a6ba1760d5671ccbfc5dbc6/Messages.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Escritorio/amigo secreto/send_sms.py", line 10, in <module>
    message = client.messages \
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\message\__init__.py", line 88, in create
    payload = self._version.create(method='POST', uri=self._uri, data=data, )
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twilio\base\version.py", line 193, in create
    response = self.request(
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twilio\base\version.py", line 39, in request
    return self.domain.request(
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twilio\base\domain.py", line 38, in request
    return self.twilio.request(
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\__init__.py", line 131, in request
    return self.http_client.request(
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twilio\http\http_client.py", line 91, in request
    response = session.send(
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twilio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACfd9e165c0a6ba1760d5671ccbfc5dbc6/Messages.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

I've never used an API before, I could really use somebody's guidance. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That error looks as though you have issues between your installation of Anaconda and the SSL module. There's a potential fix from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6424), run:

```
execstack -c anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Alternatively, other comments suggest [installing OpenSSL](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6424#issuecomment-464660808) for your environment.